# Space on partition MATE 16.04

Tags: 16.04, disk-usage, mate

I have a problem with a fresh installed MATE 16.04.3. I installed with deleting harddisk and use the entire disk, which is 1 TB on my laptop (Lenovo B50-10)
Gparted sais I have more than 839 GB free, the properties of home sais I have 8,3 GB free. I have no idea how that can be.

[image: gparted view]

[image: properties of home]

I see now, that the 2 partitions SWAP and home have no mountpoints. I haven't touched this, it's like it is from the installation

I am thankful for every proposial

Answer (score 1):

If you choose New Ubuntu install, it will install the whole system in two-partitions (/ and swap). At this case, you will not have problems with disk-space, but you are subject to userdata loss, in the case of problems with this partition.

Otherwise, it's a better practice to make a customized install (Something else option). I suggest you to reserve

- 20Gb for root (/);
- 2Gb for swap
- The remaining space for /home.

In my case, I like to store work stuff at `/opt`, as I assigned my fourth partition.

Comment: That is a good tip, /opt. I did it also, with another label.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you made a partition for home, but did not tell the installer to use it. so you are only using the 29 GB you designated for /.

Comment: I used the installer and let it do the whole work. I didn't touch the partition tables. This was automatic. I have installed Ubuntu many times before, and I newer saw a resukt like this.

Comment: I will start with live USB-stick and try to asign the mountpoints manually, hope it works

Comment: swap doesn't have a mount point. the key shows that it is being used. for some reason the /home partition didn't get used.

Answer (score 0):

I really have no idea where these 4 partitions came from, usually I install from a USB-stick prepared with systemback. I did it right now, and there I have 4 partitions,

```
/,boot-efi, swap, home
```

In this case I had to install from the start, because I switched from Ubuntu/gnome 14.04.5 to Ubuntu MATE 16.04.3. I aslo expected to find 2 and not 4 partitions.

Now I have the whole space on home agsin and can work as usual.

Thanks again

(How can I mark this solved, pretty new here).